# Can i use the OnChange event of a Editbox to handle Threads?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, synchronize

Is it a right way to get responses from a Thread through `OnChange` event of a`Editbox` by calling a `synchronize` mothod that changes value of `Editbox`?

Something like this :

```
//Extra Thread
procedure HThread.Execute;
begin
    Synchronize(CallGUI);
end;

procedure HThread.CallGUI;
begin
  Edit.Text = 'Hello';
end;


//Main Thread
procedure Main;
begin
  Tr := HThread.Create(true);
  Tr.Edit := Form1.Edit1;
  Tr.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Response from extra thread :' + Edit1.text);
end;
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to add a time-line style description of events? It's not clear to me what you'd like to do, because a `TEdit.OnChange` fires in response to changes into an edit box, and that's in the main thread. The synchronize method is something you use in a background thread to make something happen within the main VCL thread, not something you call from OnChange.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the question body (the OnChange event handler isn't "handling" anything related to a thread). The code you posted doesn't compile, so we can't really guess what you're doing. Ignoring the compiler errors, can't help but ask why aren't you calling `ShowMessage` directly from `CallGUI`. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do, as in the "final goal".

Comment: Ok, you fixed the non-compiling bit.

Comment: I think the question is clear. read the Matthias' answer pelase.

Comment: @Kermia, of course the question is clear *to you*, but it's not clear to me, not even now (those I can infer some of the missing pieces from the accepted answer). My comments are an honest attempt to help, knowing I'm not getting rep in return. Next time answer those questions, you've got nothing to lose - but you might get better answers in return.

Comment: I prefer to solve such problems with asynchronous methods. Try Queue instead of Synchronize.

Comment: @David, what "such problems"? I was going to suggest something based on `PostMessage()` but since the OP didn't reveal the actual problem, I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Comment: @cosmin general problems of updating UI to show progress of multiple threads

Comment: @David, I don't know if OP's problem fits in that category, because of the unusual requirement for `OnChange` to be fired. I doubt the actual code in the `OnChange` is a call to `ShowMessage`. For all I know it could be a "Please insert disk and press OK to continue message". I asked the OP 3 times what he's actually trying to do, twice in comments, once in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you change the EditBox text value in a procedure called via `Synchronize()` from a thread, the assigned `OnChange` event will be executed in the GUI thread. This will work with no problem but will halt your thread unitl the event is processed.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `TEdit` is troublesome, for a couple of reasons:

- It looks like you're using the `TEdit` as a place for data transfer from the thread (the reliance on the `OnChange` event handler makes me think some more processing is required, the `TEdit` isn't used as a simple "output area"). GUI elements should never be used for data storage, for countless reasons ranging from performance to OOP encapsulation and relying on algorithms outside your control.
- Relying on the `OnChange` event handler to fire when you programatically change the text is relying on implementation details of `TEdit`. What if Microsoft decides not to fire the `OnChange` event if the change was made programatically? Or Embarcadero decides to conditionally not surface it since the programmer doesn't need to be notified *he* just changed that value?

Other then that, your use of `Syncronize()` will probably work, ie "you can use it", but I'd say it's not a good idea. I'd like to suggest a better solution but can't do that, because I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. If all you want to do is force `OnChange` to be fired, then keep your code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing something in UI via `Synchronize()` is a correct way, if you mean that. I'm not sure I understood the rest of your question though.